# mail sent from google-app-engine app not appearing on my "sent items" on gmail account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, gmail

I have an application hosted on google app engine that sends mail to people under certain conditions. The mail is sent on my behalf. Earlier, each time a mail was sent, I would find the sent mail on my "Sent Items" folder in gmail. However, this does not appear to be happening consistently. I found that, a mail was sent yesterday and was successfully received by the recipient. But I do not see the mail in my "Sent Items" folder in gmail.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue when I was using Session.getDefaultInstance() to create the mail session object.  It would work for a bit and then cease to work.  After I changed to Session.getInstance(), it has worked perfectly.

Comment: hmm..I've been using Session.getDefaultInstance()..let me change it to getInstance() and try..

Comment: found over a period of time that even this fix is not a solution :(
i do not see all my sent mails in "sent mails" folder at all times..there are occassional misses

Comment: you arent reaching your gmail daily mail limits, are you?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in my test application. It did work. http://engineplay.appspot.com/

I am sending email from my email address. And found mail in both inbox and sent items.

You need to check it again.

Comment: As I said, the problem is not observed consistently. It appears in sent items for most of the times. I observed this about 3 times in my app in the past 10 days and the app has been sending mails everyday